# QS_SrvMaxConnPerIP whitelist

Tags: apache-2.2, qos

Is there way to add IP to some kind of whitelist in mod_qos? I have couple of IP which are exceeding `QS_SrvMaxConnPerIP = 50` and I don't want to set higher value for other IP's, so I would like to add my known IP's to whitelist.

I've tried add in `qos.conf` file:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx QS_Block=no
QS_SrvMaxConnExcludeIP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

But it doesn't work.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Use `QS_SrvMaxConnExcludeIP`

```
QS_SrvMaxConnExcludeIP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your IP as VIP to avoid restriction:

```
SetEnvIf Remote_Addr xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx QS_VipRequest=yes
```

Source : http://opensource.adnovum.ch/mod_qos/#privilegedusers